# Popular um select gerado por javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estou copiando campos de um formulário com javascript, porém nesse `form` dois `input` são `select` e os `option` são gerados a partir do resultado de uma `query`. Quando as cópias são criadas as `query` não rodam e portanto os `select` vem sem opções para serem selecionadas.

HTML/PHP

Como foi pago?

```
                       <?php 

                        $sql="SELECT `tpid`, `descricao` FROM `tp_pagto`";
                        $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($query))
                        {?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option>


                    <?php }?>
```

JS

```
//CLONA O CAMPO DE DESPESAS DA PAGINA NOVA VIAGEM
$(document).ready(function(){
    var next = 1;
    $(".add-more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var addto = "#outra_dcentro" + next;
        var addRemove = "#outra_dcentro" + (next);
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = '<input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="outra_ddec' + next + '" name="outra_ddec' + next + '" type="text" placeholder="Qual a despesa?" data-items="8"/><input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="outra_dvalor' + next + '" name="outra_dvalor' + next + '" type="text" placeholder="Qual o valor?" data-items="8"/><select class="form-control" id="outra_dpago' + next + '" name="outra_dpago' + next + '"><option disabled selected>Esta pago?</option><option value="nao">Não</option><option value="sim">Sim</option></select><select class="form-control" id="outra_dtppago' + next + '" name="outra_dtppago' + next + '"><option disabled selected>Como foi pago?</option><?php $sql="SELECT `tpid`, `descricao` FROM `tp_pagto`"; $query = $mysqli->query($sql); while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {?> <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option><?php }?></select><input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="outra_dnf' + next + '" name="outra_dnf' + next + '" type="text" placeholder="Numero da NF" data-items="8"/><input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control" id="outra_dforn' + next + '" name="outra_dforn' + next + '" type="text" placeholder="Fornecedor?" data-items="8"/><select class="form-control" id="outra_dcentro' + next + '" name="outra_dcentro' + next + '"><option disabled selected>Selecione o centro de custo</option><?php $sql="SELECT `centroid`, `descricao` FROM `centro`";$query = $mysqli->query($sql);while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($query)){?><option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1];?></option><?php }?>';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="remove' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div><div id="field">';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
        $("#outra_dcentro" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#outra_dcentro").val(next);  

            $('.remove-me').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_ddec" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();

                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_dvalor" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();

                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_dpago" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();

                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_dtppago" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();

                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_dnf" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();

                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_dforn" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();

                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#outra_dcentro" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();
            });
    });  


});
```

Aqui no JS a variavel `NewIn` contem todo o código dos mesmos inputs, inclusive os select/option com o problema entre outros, o `name` é mudado e então adicionado os novos campos.

Imagino que não posso rodar uma query por javascript, mas consigo passar a array do php que contem os valores do option para o JS? Ou existe uma forma mais eficiente de fazer isso?

Comment: passe o array do php em formato json e receba ele atraves de ajax no javascript, exemplo jquery, seria mais ou menos isso ?

var select = $("#selectlistas");

 $.ajax({
    url:  'urldophp.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(dados){
      $.each(dados, function(index, dado){
        var campo1  = dado.campo1;
        var campo2= dado.campo2;

        select.append($('<option>', {
          value: campo1,
          text: campo2
        }));
      });
    }
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retorne o array como json em um arquivo php

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sql="SELECT `tpid`, `descricao` FROM `tp_pagto`";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo json_encode($query)
?>
```

Receba o conteúdo desse array por uma requisição ajax e popule o select
(**Jquery**)

```
var select = $("#selectlistas"); 

$.ajax({ 
    url: 'urldophp.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    success: function(dados){ 
        $.each(dados, function(index, dado){ 
            var campo1 = dado.campo1; 
            var campo2= dado.campo2; 
            select.append($('<option>', {
                value: campo1, 
                text:  campo2 
                })); 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar usar.
Mas esse `type:'POST'` significa que preciso dar submit? Essas variáveis `campo1` e `campo2` podem ser acessadas pela função que adiciona os inputs?

Comment: não precisa ser um submit, pode chamar como funcao em um evento onclick, campo1 e campo2 sao os valores retornados no array do seu select